# Is the "Mother of all Bombs" recently dropped by U.S. the largest since Hiroshima and Nagasaki?

Tags: united-states, armed-conflict, military, nuclear-weapons

I read that the bomb dropped was the "largest conventional bomb" ever used in warfare, so therefore would that make it the largest bomb ever used in warfare all together outside of the two uses of nuclear bombs by [the United States in 1945](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_bombings_of_Hiroshima_and_Nagasaki)?

It adds up based on my historical knowledge, but I hadn't seen any media outlets from what I read and watched mention this as a fact, and was curious if it was actually true or not.

Comment: The video of Moab explosion suggests that it is a fae. It's use a couple days ago is it's first use in combat. The largest such device is foab. But that device has never been actually used. As the kill mechanism of faes is quite unpleasant there have been calls for it to be banned.

Comment: not an actual bomb but essentially the same kill mechanism as a fae: there was an explosion at a chemical storage facility in china a couple years back. lots of video of it floating around but no official tonage estimates. unofficially the figure goes over 20t. it is simply massive.

Comment: Curious why you guys put this on hold as it clearly is a government/policy question regarding use of military weapons.

Comment: @Noah - Because it isn't about policy, it's about a bomb. Asking a question about policies related to bombs is on-topic, but questions about the bomb itself are not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes, it's the biggest bomb used in combat in over 70 years.

[Reuters reported that](http://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-afghanistan-bomb-idUSKBN17F27U):

> The United States dropped "the mother of all bombs," **the largest non-nuclear device it has ever unleashed in combat**, on a network of caves and tunnels used by Islamic State in eastern Afghanistan on Thursday, the military said.
>
> *(emphasis mine)*

And [Quartz reported that](https://qz.com/958380/the-us-just-dropped-its-biggest-bomb-in-combat-in-over-70-years-on-isis-in-afghanistan/):

> The US just dropped its biggest bomb in combat in over 70 years on ISIS in Afghanistan

### Elaboration

The only time nuclear weapons were used by the US were the 2 atomic bombs used in Japan during WWII. So, since this is the largest non-nuclear device used, it is the largest bomb used since the 2 atomic bombs.

**But,**

Though it is called "Mother of all Bombs", it can't actually be compared to the 2 uses of nuclear bombs. The MOAB only has an explosive yield of only 11 tons while the hydrogen bombs US used previously has an explosive yield of 15000 tons. That's **1,363 times smaller**.

> Some overexcited coverage has even compared this bomb to a nuclear weapon, which nuclear experts think is completely absurd.
>
> “Don't be fooled by the claim circulating in some quarters that the explosive yield of the MOAB rivals that of the bomb dropped on Hiroshima,” Kingston Reif, director for disarmament and threat reduction policy at the Arms Control Association, tells me. **“The reported yield of the MOAB is approximately 11 tons. The Hiroshima bomb was approximately 15 KILOtons."**
>
> *(emphasis mine)*
>
> <sup>Source: http://www.vox.com/world/2017/4/13/15292418/moab-mother-of-all-bombs</sup>

Comment: Those quotes do not say the MOAB is the largest bomb dropped in warfare ever. This is just the biggest bomb dropped by the US.